# Are Items.length and Count always the same for DynamoDB query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

It seems a silly question. For the returned result from a dynamodb query, it has `Items` and `Count`. `Items` is an array which has a `length` property. I would like to ask are `Items.length` and `Count` always the same?

I am using javascript SDK.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#query-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `length` of `Items` and the `Count` should be the same.

A other count [fun facts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.Count):

> Each Query response will contain the ScannedCount and Count for the items that were processed by that particular Query request. To obtain grand totals for all of the Query requests, you could keep a running tally of both ScannedCount and Count.
>
> If the size of the Query result set is larger than 1 MB, then ScannedCount and Count will represent only a partial count of the total items. You will need to perform multiple Query operations in order to retrieve all of the results (see Paginating the Results).

Also, if you just care about the count and not the data, you can ask DynamoDB to only return the count via the [Select property of the request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-Select).